# Unable to merge contacts which enabled as portal users

Tags: contact, salesforce-classic, merge

As a user, unable to merge contacts which enabled as a portal users, received following error
**Error :You do not have permission to merge contacts enabled as portal users.**
But able to merge contacts which not enabled as portal users.

As a admin, using same stadard contact merge, able to merge portal contacts.
Which permission is missing for the user to merge portal enabled contacts.

Answer (score 0):

I would surmise that the running user needs [per the doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.contacts_merge_lex.htm&type=5)

**For Partner Portal contacts**

- `Delete on Contacts` and
- `Manage Partners`

**For Customer Portal Contacts**

- `Delete on Contacts`
- `Edit Self Service users`

Be aware of the [considerations for merging portal contacts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.contacts_merging_contacts_associated_with_portal_users.htm&type=5)

> You can merge a portal contact with another portal contact.
>
> You can merge Customer Community enabled person accounts with Customer Community Plus person accounts.
>
> Before you merge contacts that include partner users and customer users, decide which type of portal user to retain. The user that you don’t retain is disabled. However, after the contacts are merged, you can enable the contact for access to the portal from which it was removed during the merge process.
>
> You can merge contacts that are associated with various accounts by transferring the contacts that you want to merge into one account and then merging the contacts that are associated with the common account.